# Data annotation issue in EF

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

HI I have following entity class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace myspace
{
    class aList
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
         [Index("atIdIndex", IsUnique=true)]
        public int atId { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
      }
}
```

In visual studio on [Index("atIdIndex", IsUnique=true)] I get red line under Index and it says that 
 Type or namespace Index couldnot be found. 
Please let me know how i can fix it Thanks
'

Comment: Well, what assembly and namespace is the `IndexAttribute` class defined in?  Have you referenced that assembly and imported that namespace?

Comment: I thought it was in using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

Comment: Rather than thinking, why don't you look to find out?  The MSDN Library has documentation for every class and the class topic specifies the assembly and the namespace.  It's about 10 seconds effort to find out.

Comment: I had checked it and still it wasn't showing up in intellisense. Had to re load than worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to re install EF it worked fine after that. Thanks